# How to identify a locator in below Html code and how to write a xpath for this in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

How to identify a locator in below Html and how to write a xpath for 
    this in selenium

```
 <div>    
<div class="slds-icon-waffle" data-aura-rendered-by="231:0;p">
<div class="slds-r1" data-aura-rendered-by="232:0;p"></div>
<div class="slds-r2" data-aura-rendered-by="233:0;p"></div>
<div class="slds-r3" data-aura-rendered-by="234:0;p"></div>
<div class="slds-r4" data-aura-rendered-by="235:0;p"></div>
<div class="slds-r5" data-aura-rendered-by="236:0;p"></div>
<div class="slds-r6" data-aura-rendered-by="237:0;p"></div>
<div class="slds-r7" data-aura-rendered-by="238:0;p"></div>
<div class="slds-r8" data-aura-rendered-by="239:0;p"></div>
<div class="slds-r9" data-aura-rendered-by="240:0;p"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Are you aware of Chromes ability to generate an xpath by inspecting an element in the browser?

Comment: No. Can you please help me in this.

Comment: In google chrome: `Right Click > Inspect` then select the node and `Right Click > copy > Copy XPath`

Comment: I inspected it and i copied as X path. With that i  had already wrote xpath with class and link text. It is not working.

Comment: @SrieedherSanthakumar Can you consider showcasing your work please? Thanks

Comment: can you please tell me any other way  to write it.

Comment: @ Debanjan I am  implementing one scenario using selenium Webdriver.  In that above html tag, i tried writing xpath with classname and link text it is not clicking .can you please suggest any other measure.

Comment: @SrieedherSanthakumar Can you consider updating your Question with your research, what you tried, what error you saw and error stack trace? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can generate xpath as below using div class :

```
   //div[contains(@class,'slds-icon-waffle')]
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here class names are looking unique. you can use the following xpath to identify the first elemen.

```
//div[@class="slds-icon-waffle"]
```

for the second element

`//div[@class="slds-r1"]` and so on.

If you want to locate all elements with single xpath, then use the following.

```
//div[starts-with(@class,"slds")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing xpath is a pretty basic thing in selenium. I prefer you to learn how to write xpath first. This video might give you some idea.

http://learn-automation.com/how-to-write-dynamic-xpath-in-selenium/

Once you got some idea, try writing the xpath by yourself. If you got any issues, feel free to comment. Thanks.